# Uploading image to folder in ASP.net and C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried various answers here on StackOverflow but, none have solved the problem. I am trying to upload an image via file type to a folder called Images. The problem is that it always hits the catch in the try/catch. I have the block of code below but, removed the credentials for security. Please help!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string http = "https://serverName";
    string httpFolder = "/Images";
    byte[] fileBytes = null;

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd());
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http + httpFolder + fileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
        request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
        request.EnableSsl = false;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        response.Close();
        ViewBag.FileUploaded = "File uploaded succesfully!"; 
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {

        throw new Exception((ex.Response as FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("UploadPhoto");
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? What are the details of the error?

Comment: @Jasen FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http + httpFolder + fileName);

Cant cast FtpWebReques

Comment: You are using the http protocol to make an ftp request giving you the type cast error.